# Changing Cell Date Formats to Text Format and Retain mm/dd/yy

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to change cell dates with a general format (mm/dd/yy) to a text format for uploading to Peoplesoft. However I must retain the `mm/dd/yy`. When I change the cell from general format to text format it then changes the date to a serial number date such as `41982` etc. I don't want the serial number date. It must remain a text format cell with `mm/dd/yy` or `mm/dd/yyyy` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Select the cells containing dates you wish to convert to formatted text and run this tiny macro:

```
Sub TextDate()
    Dim r As Range, st As String
    For Each r In Selection
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            r.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
            st = r.Text
            r.Clear
            r.NumberFormat = "@"
            r.Value = st
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as **.xlsm** rather than **.xlsx**

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Thanks Gary's Student! That seems to be the solution. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

> When I change the cell from general format to text format ...

The correct choice is the "Date" format in that dialog.

Dates are stored as numbers, a day count from a base date - i.e. each added "1" is 24 hours added.
The base date varies depending on the related settings in Excel.

If you need the cells to contain the FORMATTED TEXT;

- then make sure you see the dates in the format you need them
- Select the cells (Hold CTRL to select non-adjacent cells)
- Select Copy from the menu or the Ribbon
- Select Paste Special from menu or Ribbon
- Select "Paste values" from the dialog and click OK

Comment: I think OP needs it to be in text format for Peoplesoft to accept it. However, it has to be a text value in the format MM/DD/YYYY.

Comment: The OP says exactly what I put on the first line, that isn't perfectly clear on the meaning.

Comment: Clarified along the meaning you indicate.

Comment: -1, "Paste Values" still copies the numbers, this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If the intent is to take a date column in your input and use it in SQL to load to a PS table, I would set the column format to the date setup you need.  Once you're clear on how PS needs the date (which is DB-specific and takes some trial and error), you can then create an SQL format call using TO_DATE.  For example, if the date needs to be MM/DD/YYYY for 11/26/2018, the command would look like TO_DATE('11/26/2018','MM/DD/YYYY').  The first variable captures the data to be entered and the second defines the formatting.  Another way using this would be to strip the dashes from your date and use the format variable to define the date layout: TO_DATE('11262018','MMDDYYYY').  Most processes that would feed this raw data and formatting is able to then format it to your database date standards rather than making you guess at it.